# Updated Model for Entity Framework and got complicated error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I get this message when I'm trying to run my application:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'MVC2_1Context' context has changed since the database was created...

The application has worked before, the only thing I have done, is to add some Data Annotations in the model and reference a property to an Enum in a new class.

To solve this I thought it should be enough to use `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console and type in Enable-Migration -EnableAutomaticMigrations` and then hit enter! But I still get this error message and hope to get som help here to be able to continue!

Comment: Open up the package manager console and type: `update-database`.  Then run your application again.

Comment: @JohnH Thanks for your comment, but dispite that I use update-database -force, I get the same error. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Additional information: The model backing the 'MVC2_1Context' context
>   has changed since the database was created.

It means one of your classes use in the *MVC2_1Context*  has changed, but the database hasn't been updated so is now out of date.

for more info:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx